# YouTube embeds Cross-Origin Request Blocked (CORB) error

Tags: php, functions, iframe

I am new to the WordPress world, please bare with me.

On my website have embedded some YouTube videos using the video block. I am seeing this error in the console:

```
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://googleads.g.doubleclick.net/pagead/id. (Reason: CORS request did not succeed). Status code: (null).
```

I have enabled the CORS header in .htaccess as followed.

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
     Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin *
</IfModule>
```

Why do is still see an error?

Thanks kocjs

Answer (score 1):

I have found out that i have enabled tracking protection in that particular Firefox profile.
A relevant warning, which i oversaw by just displaying the errors, was also displayed.

```
The resource at “https://googleads.g.doubleclick.net/pagead/id” was blocked because content blocking is enabled.
```

Apparently https://googleads.g.doubleclick.net/pagead/id. does honor the tracking protection setting.

Today i learned to use a clean browser profile to debug my website...

kocjs